# Can I apply Weierstrass theorem to a half open interval?

Tags: calculus

I guess that if it’s a half open interval it should only assure that it has either a global maximum or a global minimum but not both. I’m not sure that I’m right. Does it works that way?

Comment: How about $f(x)=\frac{\sin(1/x)}x$ for $0<x\leq1$?

Comment: I’m not sure about my answer. f(x) it’s discontinuous at 0 so it’s not continuous on the [0,1] interval but since it’s a half open interval like (0,1] I don’t know if that means that it’s continuous there

Comment: Yes, of course it's continuous on $(0,1]$.  It's continuous at each point of the interval.  If it could be extended to a continuous function on the closed interval, your statement would be trivially true.

Comment: So I can use the Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Use the theorem to do what?  The statement in your question is false, as my example shows.

Comment: To prove that exist global maximum and minimum values on that’s interval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126480/discussion-between-gzanotto-and-saulspatz).